# sqlite - delete and get all values of some column from affected rows

Tags: c++, sqlite

How to delete some rows from the table and get all there `IDs` after deletion.

**Example:**

```
"sessions" table with columns: sessionid, timestamp    

std::string sql_dropallrecords = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE timestamp < 1000000";  
if( sqlite3_exec(db, sql_dropallrecords.c_str(), 0, 0, 0) != SQLITE_OK ) {
    sqlite3_close (db);
    return; 
}
```

How to get all affected sessionids after execution of this query or suggest other good solution to do this.

**thoughts:** So, seems I can wrap SELECT, then DELETE statement and the TRANSACTION. But the question how to get it working at c++ ? So, SELECT statement under c++ used `sqlite3_step`, but will `sqlite3_step` return some results if it's running under transaction?

Comment: `will sqlite3_step return some results if it's running under transaction?` Yes it will. Transactions would have been pretty useless if statements didn't work inside of them. `But the question how to get it working at c++ ?` There are plenty of examples of using SQLite in C++. Do you have a more specific problem you would like some help with?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, the main question is how to do this at the one step, because SELECT then DELETE will made two same searches on the BD. (same part WHERE timestamp < 100000)

Comment: You can't do that in one step. You need SELECT then DELETE. Alternatively, you could do a SELECT, and issue a one-row DELETE for each row as you iterate over them, as in `DELETE FROM sessions WHERE sessionid=?;` This might or might not be faster, depending on the indexes your table has.